# home-brew npm not being used , npm system being used

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I installed Node using `Homebrew`. That install came with npm version 14.8.0. When I use command `npm -v` , I get back version 6.14.7. I have tried uninstalling node with home-brew and reinstalling. I also found the folder that the `npm` version 6.14.7 was located in and deleted it. After I did this, I reinstalled node using home-brew and now everything is the same. What gives ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some PATH issue, which `brew doctor` can tell exactly why. Ideally, after installation, it should be good to go. Sometimes, you do need `brew link node` to link the homebrew version, but I don't think that is your case.

Let me know if that works. If still failed, please attach both `brew config` and `brew doctor` for debugging. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to use doctor and link, then unlink and relink using brew. All of which go through fine. I event did brew upgrade npm and it said that the latest version was already installed . but when I run npm --version or npm -v the terminal message is still showing an older version of npm. Thats the part that is very confusing and has me going for a loop.

Comment: 1 saulv  admin  30 Aug 18 01:00 /usr/local/bin/node -> ../Cellar/node/14.8.0/bin/node

Comment: That is the message I get when I typed what you asked me to.

Comment: Then you should be see something like this, `$ /usr/local/Cellar/node/14.8.0/libexec/bin/npm --version
6.14.7`

Comment: I am very sure it is your PATH issue.

Comment: can you ensure this is in your PATH, `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Also you can do something like this, export PATH=$PATH:"/usr/local/bin"

Comment: let me know how it goes.

Comment: ok I ran the above command. I ran brew update npm and then checked npm -v  and got the same result as before.

Comment: Can you attach each of the command in your origin post? Also please attach `brew config` and `brew doctor` in your OP.

Comment: brew config 
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 2.4.12
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 19ef93288573e565cec82679d0cd834a4ad080ab
Last commit: 3 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: f1a1ca8f96ab3b315d71a7faa9917191a5af01a3
Core tap last commit: 12 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 12
CPU: dodeca-core 64-bit kabylake

Comment: Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
Clang: 11.0 build 1103
Git: 2.28.0 => /usr/local/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl CLT: 1103.0.32.62

Comment: The above is all brew config. Below is brew doctor.                                                     saulv@MacBook-Pro ~ % brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.